# Convert pandas dataframe to distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the distances between names like this:

| name1 | name2 | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | John | 3.4 |
| John | James | 2.3 |
| James | Peter | 1.4 |

I need to convert it to a distance matrix like this. (The distances with the same names (that are always 0) are not in the original dataframe):

| matrix | John | Peter | James |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 3.4 | 2.3 |
| Peter | 3.4 | 0 | 1.4 |
| James | 2.3 | 1.4 | 0 |

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

here is one way useing pivot :

```
df1 = df.pivot(index = 'name1', columns = 'name2', values='distance').fillna(0)
df2 = df.pivot(index = 'name2', columns = 'name1', values='distance').fillna(df1)

df2
```

output :

```
>>>
name1  James  John  Peter
name2                    
James    0.0   2.3    1.4
John     2.3   0.0    3.4
Peter    1.4   3.4    0.0
```

Comment: +10 good idea. Along these lines, you could also concat the bidirectional distances before pivoting: `pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'name2': 'name1', 'name1': 'name2'})]).pivot(index='name1', columns='name2').fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `pivot` and `combine_first` with its own transpose:

```
df2 = df.pivot(index='name1', columns='name2', values='distance')
df2 = df2.combine_first(df2.T).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
       James  John  Peter
name1                    
James    0.0   2.3    1.4
John     2.3   0.0    3.4
Peter    1.4   3.4    0.0
```

As pipeline:

```
df2 = (df
       .pivot(index='name1', columns='name2', values='distance')
       .pipe(lambda d: d.combine_first(d.T))
       .fillna(0)
       )
```